# Map in R, how do I draw a map of Baltimore?

Tags: r, plot, shiny, coordinates, render

I'm trying to do a Shiny app, and a part of it, consists into a plot of Baltimore city, and once I have this, I will print other data on this map.

I've been trying 'rworldmap', 'raster' and 'ggmap', but I'm not getting how to put the right parameters to make it work, the time i've been closer is this:

```
library(rworldmap)
newmap <- getMap(resolution = "low")
plot(newmap)
library(rworldmap)
newmap <- getMap(resolution = "low")
plot(newmap)

plot(newmap,
  xlim = c(-39.3750, -76.7226),
  ylim = c(39.1800, -76.5254),
  asp = 1
)
```

It appears to me the south-america region, and... upside down :S

Latitude and longitude in theory should be aprox:
(39.371846,-76.720619)
(39.198588,-76.491280)

Anyone know how should I continue with this?

Sorry for my english,

Thanks! :)

P.S:If this can help, what I'll print later will be coordinates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `ggmap`:

```
library(ggmap)
map <- get_map(location = 'Baltimore', zoom = 12)
ggmap(map)
```

Comment: Lot's of thanks Andrew ! I don't realise it could be that easy. Now I'll try to fit it all to the shiny part.